# Problems starting Replication on large databases - SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have been battling SQL Server for a week trying to get replication up and running, now I realize that most probably I am doing something wrong and I hope that one of you can help pointing me in the right direction.

I want to start replication of a big (180GB) database in my lab environment and every time the end result is errors of the type "The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated command. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 20598)".

There are more than one database to be replicated and the smaller ones (<= 4GB) have started without problems, a medium database of 21GB had one similar error and has been running for a few days since I found and inserted the missing data in the subscriber DB.

A couple of facts:
- I have set up the distributor as a remote distributor since the publishers are mirrored databases.
- I assume the distributor setup is OK since all the replicated databases are taking the same 'path' and the smaller ones are working.
- The distributor and the subscriber are set up on the same server.
- All in all the following procedure takes about 3.5-4 hours.
- The database is running in Full Recovery mode
- All log backups on the publisher are turned off for the duration.

Here's what I do:
**On the publisher**
Create the publication and add all the articles

```
use [Zaragoza]
exec sp_replicationdboption @dbname = N'Zaragoza',
                            @optname = N'publish',
                            @value = N'true'
GO
exec [Zaragoza].sys.sp_addlogreader_agent @job_login = N'NS-LAB-DB-40\SqlServiceUser',
                                          @job_password = N'********',  -- Modify Here
                                          @publisher_security_mode = 1,
                                          @job_name = null
GO
-- Adding the transactional publication
exec sp_addpublication @publication = N'Zaragoza_Full',
                       @description = N'Transactional publication of database ''Zaragoza'' from Publisher ''NS-LAB-DB-38''.',
                       @sync_method = N'concurrent',
                       @retention = 0,
                       @allow_push = N'true',
                       @allow_pull = N'true',
                       @allow_anonymous = N'false',
                       @enabled_for_internet = N'false',
                       @snapshot_in_defaultfolder = N'true',
                       @compress_snapshot = N'false',
                       @ftp_port = 21,
                       @allow_subscription_copy = N'false',
                       @add_to_active_directory = N'false',
                       @repl_freq = N'continuous',
                       @status = N'active',
                       @independent_agent = N'true',
                       @immediate_sync = N'true',  -- Needs TRUE
                       @allow_sync_tran = N'false',
                       @allow_queued_tran = N'false',
                       @allow_dts = N'false',
                       @replicate_ddl = 1,
                       @allow_initialize_from_backup = N'true',  -- Modify Here
                       @enabled_for_p2p = N'false',
                       @enabled_for_het_sub = N'false'
GO

/* SHOULD not need this since no snapshots will be generated
exec sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'Zaragoza_Full', 
                                @frequency_type = 1, 
                                @frequency_interval = 1, 
                                @frequency_relative_interval = 1, 
                                @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, 
                                @frequency_subday = 8, 
                                @frequency_subday_interval = 1, 
                                @active_start_time_of_day = 0, 
                                @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, 
                                @active_start_date = 0, 
                                @active_end_date = 0, 
                                @job_login = N'NS-LAB-DB-40\SqlServiceUser', 
                                @job_password = N'********', 
                                @publisher_security_mode = 1
*/

exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'Zaragoza_Full', 
                   @article = N'__MigrationLog', 
                   @source_owner = N'dbo', 
                   @source_object = N'__MigrationLog', 
                   @type = N'logbased', 
                   @description = null, 
                   @creation_script = null, 
                   @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', 
                   @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F, 
                   @identityrangemanagementoption = N'manual', 
                   @destination_table = N'__MigrationLog', 
                   @destination_owner = N'dbo', 
                   @vertical_partition = N'false', 
                   @ins_cmd = N'CALL sp_MSins_dbo__MigrationLog', 
                   @del_cmd = N'CALL sp_MSdel_dbo__MigrationLog', 
                   @upd_cmd = N'SCALL sp_MSupd_dbo__MigrationLog'
GO
-- MANY more "EXEC sp_addarticle"....
```

**On the publisher**
I recompile the subscription SPs since I had problems with them once.
I use the output from the following statement:

```
USE Zaragoza;
EXEC sp_scriptpublicationcustomprocs @publication=N'Zaragoza_Full';
```

**On the publisher**
I backup the database & log

```
BACKUP DATABASE Zaragoza TO DISK = 'E:\Backup\Zaragoza_FULL.bkp' WITH INIT, STATS=5;
BACKUP LOG Zaragoza TO DISK = 'E:\Backup\Zaragoza_LOG.bkp' WITH INIT, STATS=5;
```

**On the subscriber**
Copy the backups from the publisher

```
CD /D E:\Backup
COPY /Y \\NS-LAB-DB-38-mirror\Backup\Zaragoza_FULL.bkp .
COPY /Y \\NS-LAB-DB-38-mirror\Backup\Zaragoza_LOG.bkp .
```

**On the subscriber**
Restore the database and log backups

```
USE [master]
GO

RESTORE DATABASE Zaragoza_Sub
FROM DISK = 'E:\Backup\Zaragoza_FULL.bkp'
WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS=5,
     MOVE 'Zaragoza' TO 'I:\mssql_repl\Zaragoza_Sub\Zaragoza_Sub.mdf',
     MOVE 'Zaragoza_log' TO 'I:\mssql_repl\Zaragoza_Sub\Zaragoza_Sub_log.ldf';
GO

RESTORE LOG Zaragoza_Sub
FROM DISK = 'E:\Backup\Zaragoza_LOG.bkp'
     WITH RECOVERY, STATS=25;
GO
```

**On the subscriber**
Remove all triggers since I noticed that they interfered with the replication SPs

```
USE Zaragoza_Sub;

DECLARE @Trigger nvarchar(100),
        @SQL nvarchar(2000);

DECLARE curTriggers CURSOR
    LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT tr.name TriggerName--, te.type_desc TriggerType, ob.name TableName, tr.is_disabled, c.text
    FROM sys.triggers tr INNER JOIN
         sys.trigger_events te ON tr.object_id = te.object_id INNER JOIN
         sys.objects ob ON tr.parent_id = ob.object_id;

OPEN curTriggers;
FETCH NEXT FROM curTriggers INTO @Trigger;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TRIGGER dbo.' + @Trigger + ';';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
    FETCH NEXT FROM curTriggers INTO @Trigger;
END;
CLOSE curTriggers;
DEALLOCATE curTriggers;
```

**On the publisher**
Add the subscription and the push agent

```
-----------------BEGIN: Script to be run at Publisher 'NS-LAB-DB-38'-----------------
-----------------                           *********               -----------------
use [Zaragoza]

exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'Zaragoza_Full',
                        @subscriber = N'NS-LAB-DB-40',
                        @destination_db = N'Zaragoza_Sub',
                        @subscription_type = N'Push',
                        @sync_type = N'initialize with backup',  --@sync_type = N'replication support only',
                        @status = N'active',  -- ADD this line
                        @article = N'all',
                        @update_mode = N'read only',
                        @subscriber_type = 0,
                        @backupdevicetype=N'disk',
                        @backupdevicename=N'E:\backup\Zaragoza_LOG.bkp';

exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent @publication = N'Zaragoza_Full',
                                  @subscriber = N'NS-LAB-DB-40',
                                  @subscriber_db = N'Zaragoza_Sub',
                                  @job_login = N'NS-LAB-DB-40\SqlServiceUser',
                                  @job_password = N'********',   -- Modify Here
                                  @subscriber_security_mode = 1,
                                  @frequency_type = 64,
                                  @frequency_interval = 0,
                                  @frequency_relative_interval = 0,
                                  @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0,
                                  @frequency_subday = 0,
                                  @frequency_subday_interval = 0,
                                  @active_start_time_of_day = 0,
                                  @active_end_time_of_day = 235959,
                                  @active_start_date = 20140618,
                                  @active_end_date = 99991231,
                                  @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False',
                                  @dts_package_location = N'Distributor';
GO
-----------------END: Script to be run at Publisher 'NS-LAB-DB-38'-----------------
```

The worst part is that this is only a LAB system, when I apply this to Live I will have to deal with a 24/7 environment with 10,000+ transactions a day, so downtime is a total No-No.

If you are missing any details do not hesitate to ask, I will gladly provide all the details I have.

Have a great day

DS

Comment: Did you tried run this with highest level of verbose logging ?

Comment: This lonk can help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/07/13/using-verbose-history-agent-profile-while-troubleshooting-replication.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/03/04/kb-article-312292-how-to-enable-replication-agents-for-logging-to-output-files-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Thanks Kuba, I didn't know there were different levels of logging. I will try this over the weekend or next week.